# how to get username on every page in php

Tags: php, mysql

i wanted to store username of current logged in user

```
 mysql_query(" UPDATE  member SET url = 'ques2.php'
WHERE username = '$username' ") or die('Unable to update members URL: ' . mysql_error());
```

//in this i wanted to update my column url which is the last visited url of the logged in user
  i had used this to retireve my username

```
    while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data ))
{
    //Print $info['username'] ;
    if($info['username']==($fgmembersite->UserName('username')))
    {

        $username=$info['username'];

        break;
    }
}
```

but it is not retrieving the username of the logged in user AND I WANT TO STORE IT IN VARIBLE SO THAT I CAN RUN MY UPDATE QUERY....what is the problem in my code....please help.

Comment: You're using `mysql_query` in a way that's vulnerable to SQL injection attacks because you haven't escaped `$username`. Using [PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) would be a much safer solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Store it in session:

```
$_SESSION['username'] = $info['username'];
```

Then on other pages, you can get it from that:

```
echo $_SESSION['username'];
```

Make sure to put `session_start()` on top of every page where you use it.

Comment: Also, session has to be started before any output, and yaddayaddayadda

Comment: @Sarfraz why are you saying that put session_start() on top of every page....session_start() should be put only when user is logged in correctly..i mean if login username and pwd is correct than strat the session...why i need to put it every time?...plese tell if iam wrong.

Comment: @user1253753: On any page you want to use the php's keyword `$_SESSION` then on that page only you will have to put session_start.

Comment: @Sarfraz..my code is working now but iam unable to understand why i was wrong before...that was also a correct method...what is wrong with that method...and than what logically $_SESSION is doing for me..plz clarify my doubt.

Comment: @user1253753: When you store something into a session, you can use that on other pages too. Sessions have time of how long they should retain values. You can read more about it here: http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php

Answer (score 1):

first page

```
 session_start();
 $_SESSION['userName'] = 'Root';
```

second page

```
  session_start();

  echo $_SESSION['userName'];
```